# EPPlus next row

Tags: c#, epplus

I am using Epplus to write out a collection into an excel file. Currently I am incrementing rows by manually manipulating the cell number.(ws is an instance of ExcelWorkSheet)

```
  int i = 1;
  foreach (var item in items)
   {
      ws.Cells["A"+i.ToString()].Value =item.Text; 
      i++;
    }
```

Instead of adding number to cell name is there a better way to handle this? Something like

```
 int i = 1;
      foreach (var item in items)
       {
          ws.Row[i].Cells[0]=item.Text; 
          i++;
        }
```

Comment: Does that make sense? The first loop iterates your items whereas the second the worksheet rows. The first column should have  the same value in every cell?

Comment: You are correct, I modified the question. What I am looking for is how to go row by row.

Comment: Side-note: You can use `LoadFromCollection` (or `LoadFromDataTable`), then you just have to take care of the data and not of the cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an [`[int Row, int Col]` indexer](https://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EPPlus/ExcelRange.cs) on `Cells` (type `ExcelRange`), so you can use `ws.Cells[i, 0]`.

```
  int i = 1;
  foreach (var item in items)
   {
      ws.Cells[i, 0].Value =item.Text; 
      i++;
    }
```